# Is there a better way to convert panda Dataframe to Tensor DataSet with features and labels separated like loading API dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, tensorflow

I want to load panda DataFrame similar on how API dataset is being parsed.

```
(train_images, train_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

I followed this function from tensorflow.org tutorial that converts CSV file to panda DataFrame then in to tensor dataset but the output dataset has a features and label both inside it.

```
# A utility method to create a tf.data dataset from a Pandas Dataframe
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe.pop('target')
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds

batch_size = 5 # A small batch sized is used for demonstration purposes
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Is there a way to make the features and label separated just like loading API?

Comment: Or is there a way to separate it from train_ds dataset?

Comment: what's the problem exactly? what do you mean features and labels separated?

Comment: The problem is a classification problem - either 0 and 1. Just like this one: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv. Features means the data of each label. Label means the classifier - either 0 or 1. Now, on the example on the link, both feature and label is on one dataset. I want it to be separated like this one on the link - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification.